# Jumpy mouse wheel zoom in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I'm using `ol.View` option `constrainResolution: true` so that mouse scroll zooming has the same zooming steps as clicking in `+` or `-` zoom control. There are no custom view resolutions set, just plain XYZ map and plain view:

```
var openTopoLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    attributions: '&copy <a href="https://opentopomap.org/about">OpenTopoMap</a>'
  }),
  title: 'OpenTopo',
  type: 'base'
});

var view = new ol.View({
  projection: currProjCode,
  center: ol.extent.getCenter(currProjExtent),
  minZoom: minZoom,
  maxZoom: maxZoom,
  zoom: initialZoom,
  smoothResolutionConstraint: false,
  constrainResolution: true
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [openTopoLayer]
});
```

Mouse wheel zooms works OK as far as resolutions are concerned, but it is not smooth. It is performed in two steps: first to half of the zoom step, then it stops and then the rest. Clicking on  `+` or `-` zoom control zooms smoothly all the way.

I tried to find related option setting in controls and interactions, but without success. The closest seemd to be `maxDelta` option of `ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom`, but it didn't help.

EDIT: After some more testing I found out that this problem appears in version 6.2.1, but not in version 6.1.1, so it seems to be a bug.

Comment: There was a bug with mousewheel zoom combined with constrainResolution and there has have been other recent dev changes to mouse and touch.  Try linking to (or downloading) the latest dev build 
https://openlayers.org/en/master/build/ol.js 
https://openlayers.org/en/master/build/ol.js.map 
https://openlayers.org/en/master/css/ol.css 
https://openlayers.org/en/master/css/ol.css.map

Comment: @Mike Thanks. I did some more testing and it discovered that this works just fine in 6.1.1. Problem is definitely present in 6.2.1.

Comment: @Mike I tried the latest dev build and it's OK with this one.

Comment: @Mike Is this fix in the v6.3.1 build?